# Edit text on Popuphover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to edit some text on popover

there is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/VUZhL/)

Click on button to see Popover

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover"
   data-content="This is the body of Popover"
   data-original-title="Creativity Tuts">pop
</a>
```

I just want to show textarea within textbox

Can we edit text on popup over ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to show a textbox within popover for editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-html` attribute of the popover. Check the JSFIDDLE edit, Its very basic example.

http://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/1449/

For more info browse the docs : [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)